# How to configure enable php_pdo_mysql on php5.5.12 and Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, pdo

After uninstalled IIS from the server, I installed Apache 2.4 64-bit on Windows Server 2008 R2. Additionally, I installed PHP 5.5.12 64-bit.

I followed the instructions on this this "[How install Apache 2.4 and PHP](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/)"

Everything seems to be fine. But What I am having difficulty with is enabling the php_pdo_mysql. I uncommented both lines in the php.ini file located on c:/php/php.ini

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Then I rebooted the Apache server "for the services list" but the pdo_mysql extension is not loading it as it should.

here are some snapshots from my php info 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
More, this is the output on the 
shell>php -m

[image]

here are the files from my server
[image]
[image]

What else do I need to do to enable pdo_mysql?
What else can I check for?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I figure out the problem.

I need to add the following to windows environment variables

```
;c:\php;c:\apache24;c:\apache24\bin;
```

After that rebooted Apache and it worked with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

You must load the PDO dll, not the default mysql extensions.

Add the following two lines to your configuration:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

These lines load the [PDO extensions](http://www.php.net/pdo). Your lines load the [MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) and [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension.

Comment: hi from what I read php_pdo.dll is only needed for older version <=5.2  but I added the lines you suggested and it is not working. I did restart my Apache also. This is what I have now extension=php_mysql.dll extension=php_pdo.dll extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: Yes, you are right. `php_pdo.dll` does not even exist anymore. You can remove this line. Does the `php_pdo_mysql.dll` exist in the extension directory? Did something change in the output of `phpinfo()`? (You are editing the correct `php.ini`, do you? The output of `phpinfo()` tells you what `php.ini` it parsed.)

Comment: The file exists in the ext directory.   I am editing the php.ini file that is located on c:/php.  This should be the valid location. Where else would the config file be located? I don't see any changes in the php info page

Comment: At the top is a line `Loaded Configuration File`, which says what file was loaded. Is this the file you are editing?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Loaded Configuration File = C:\php\php.ini. I have added one more screenshot to my question to show you the list of the configuration

Comment: That is weird. Search for `extension_dir` which is in the core section. In this directory should be the `php_pdo_mysql.dll`. Is this the true?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52054/discussion-between-mike-and-ghostgambler)